# The results of merge code are inconsistent with expectations

Tags: git, gitlab

There is a strange result after merging code. The operations are as follow:

1.Create a branch from `master` named `release_test`, which just contains one `userDO2VONew` method in AdminUserHServiceImpl.java.
[image]

2.The branch `develop` also just contains one `userDO2VONew` method.

3.Merge the `develop` branch to `release_test` branch
[image]

4.But the result of AdminUserHServiceImpl.java contains two `userDO2VONew` methods.
[image]

The version of gitlab is GitLab Community Edition [12.3.5]

What should I check first for this problem?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any `.gitattributes` files in your repository, and if so, what are their contents?

Comment: could you tell me where is the repository location? is it in the gitlab server?

Comment: You should be able to see any by using `git ls-files | grep -F '.gitattributes'`.